# control navbar swich django

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a [project](https://supremejobs.herokuapp.com/) and I'm trying to control navbar logo color change, after you visit `about` page on my app, navbar should change color and half off it needs to be yellow so it will reflect on the purple background properly.

This project is build in django and I'm including my `navbar` inside my `base` template using standard template tag `{% include 'navbar.html' %}`, and I'm `{extends 'base.html' %}` to `about` page, standard `django` template inheritance,

but I'm failing to understand how can I control my `navbar` logo, so is there a way that I can control this, and how, can I restrict my `navbar` to just one template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by including logo into separate block and then overriding where you need.

`base.html`:

```
{% block navbar %}
   ...
   <div class='logo'></div>
   ...
{% endblock navbar %}
```

`about.html`:

```
{% block navbar %}
   ...
   <div class='logo red'></div>
   ...
{% endblock navbar %}
```

Comment: yes I just did exactly that, but nevertheless thanks for the answer, some times solutions are pop out after I wrote the problem down, I think I need to use pen and paper more often